# Yii2 Elasticsearch extension - how do I handle type mapping?

Tags: php, json, elasticsearch, yii2, yii2-extension

I want to be able to store a json object in my ES index. Here's an example of what I'm trying to store (this a serialized model, a request body that is sent to ES):

```
"{"id":218,"name":"Test2","category_id":1,"address":"Pushkin street","phone":null,"site":null,"location":{"lat":64,"lon":70},"city":"Heaven","description":"Super company","tags":["#test1","#test2"]}"
```

When I try to store it (via the extension, of course), here's the error that ES returns:

```
"{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse [location]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse [location]","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"unknown property [lat]"}},"status":400}"
```

It seems that I am unable to do so without having a specific type mapping, like in the docs:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-object-type.html

However, I don't seem to find a way to provide that mapping inside the model. The extension's documentation doesn't really say anything about it.
So, my question is: do I need it at all, and if I do, how?

Appreciate all feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume your model is `\yii\elasticsearch\ActiveRecord`. You'll need to describe its attributes:

```
public function attributes()
{
  return [
    'name',
    'category_id',
    'address',
    'phone',
    'site',
    'location',
    'city',
    'description',
    'tags'
  ];
}
```

Don't forget to configure `index()` and `type()`. In the following example `type` is `my_address`.

Then you'll need to [create an index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/indices-create-index.html) with [proper field mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/mapping-core-types.html). Here's what your mapping should look like:

```
"mappings" : {
  "my_address" : {
    "properties" : {
      "name" : { "type" : "string"},
      "category_id" : { "type" : "integer"},
      "address" : { "type" : "string"},
      "phone" : { "type" : "string"},
      "site" : { "type" : "string"},
      "location" : { "type" : "geo_point"},
      "city" : { "type" : "string"},
      "description" : { "type" : "string"},
      "tags" : { "type" : "string"}
    }
  }
}
```

Note three things:

1. Location is of type `geo_point`.
2. Tags are declared as `string`. This will also allow them to be arrays of strings.
3. I didn't include the id field. If it's unique, I suggest you just set your yii model's id to the necessary value (`$model->primaryKey = '123'`). Otherwise your ES model will have its internal id set to something like `AVDXmfJ3Ou7LzqD1DDMj` and also have an id field which is not very convenient.

I encourage you to take a closer look at the mappings - they are very important when it comes to configuring how exactly the strings are being analyzed.

**UPDATE:** You don't really describe the mapping anywhere in your model. Do it in a migration - similar to creating tables in SQL.

Comment: Thanks. While I figured it out, this confirmed what I figured out. By the way, one more question: can I somehow define sorting in a ES activequery? Didn't find a way yet.

Comment: You just need to pass an array to `orderBy()`. Look up the exact structure [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html), but usually something like `[["name" => "desc"], ["date" => "asc"]]`.

Answer (score 1):

In case you using ElasticSearch ActiveRecord , you could define a method for setupMapping

```
Class BookIndex extends yii\elasticsearch\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * sets up the index for this record
     *
     */
    public static function setUpMapping()
    {
        $db = static::getDb();

        //in case you are not using elasticsearch ActiveRecord so current class extends database ActiveRecord yii/db/activeRecord
        // $db = yii\elasticsearch\ActiveRecord::getDb();

        $command = $db->createCommand();

        /*
         * you can delete the current mapping for fresh mapping but this not recommended and can be dangrous.
         */

        // $command->deleteMapping(static::index(), static::type());

        $command->setMapping(static::index(), static::type(), [
            static::type() => [
                // "_id" => ["path" => "id", "store" => "yes"],
                "properties" => [
                    'name'           => ["type" => "string"],
                    'author_name'    => ["type" => "string"],
                    'publisher_name' => ["type" => "string"],
                    'created_at'     => ["type" => "long"],
                    'updated_at'     => ["type" => "long"],
                    'status'         => ["type" => "long"],

                ],
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Later on you just need to call this method any time you want to apply the new mapping.